# Show message on checkout page if customer is not in a EU

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer

I want to display a specific content block whenever a customer is finishing his order and he is not located inside an EU-Country (like Swiss or Russia or America).

How can I achieve this?

I was thinking about creating a custom module that extends the checkout and checks for specific order details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom block using xml:

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml" >
                <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="mytemplate/message.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

create a file **message.phtml** under **/template/mytemplate/** folder

And in **/app/design/frontend/mypackeage/mytheme/template/checkout/success.phtml** put this line where you want to show the mesage.

```
<?php 
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$lastOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$shippingAddress = $lastOrder->getShippingAddress();
$someAllowedCountryId = 'UN'; // all
// Now you can put your logic here for show or hide the block
    if($shippingAddress['country_id']==$someAllowedCountryId) {
        $this->getChildHtml('customblock');
    }

?>
```

Above code is just sample please modify it according to your need.

Comment: Any chance that I can do this with a module rather then editing existing template files?

Comment: Addition: where to put XML? Any specific XML?

Comment: you can put it your local.xml

Comment: Thanks for the update. :) When I've checked your answer (in a week or so) I'll accept your answer as the correct answer if it works.